# MS Project - reset to custom view via ribbon button

Tags: vba, ms-project

So I want to develop a custom ribbon with a button, which upon clicking would switch to a custom view. This ribbon + button would live in the global template, so upon Project_Open event, it would add the ribbon to MS Project, and it would be usable.

I made the custom ribbon via code, and I have the button working.

My only problem is, that when I click the button, I want the custom view to reset to it's "Original form", meaning that if I add/remove columns, or change anything regarding formatting, I would want those to be gone, whenever I click the button.

I can see that the "ResetView" functionality doesn't work like this, since it will reset the custom view completely to it's core view.

How can I achieve this, other than building up the view programmatically from the button click?

Answer (score 0):

Have two copies of the view but each with a different, but identical, table. When the button is clicked, apply the backup view, delete the master view & table, make a copy of the backup view, and apply it:

```
Sub RestoreView()

    Const ViewName As String = "My Custom View"
    Const TableName As String = "My Custom Table"
    Const BackupView As String = "z My Custom View"

    ViewApply BackupView
    Application.OrganizerDeleteItem pjViews, ActiveProject.Name, ViewName
    Application.OrganizerDeleteItem pjTables, ActiveProject.Name, TableName
    Application.ViewEditSingle Name:=BackupView, Create:=False, NewName:=ViewName, Table:=TableName
    ViewApply ViewName

End Sub
```